# Getting seasonality, residual numbers back from multiplicative seasonal_decompose?

Tags: python, statsmodels

`seasonal_decompose` with the `model = 'multiplicative'` gives back residuals and seasonal values that need to be multiplied by the trend to get back the actual/ observed data values.

I was wondering if there was a mathematical operation I could carry on over these multiplicative values to get the "true" effect? i.e.- get back an additive set of data while retaining the changing magnitude?

I have this which is obviously wrong, but should give some idea on what I'm trying to do:

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(values, freq=365, model = 'mu', extrapolate_trend = 30) 

seasonal = decomposition.seasonal * decomposition.trend - decomposition.trend
residual = decomposition.resid * decomposition.trend - decomposition.trend
trend = decomposition.trend

values - trend - seasonal - residual
#Does not equal 0
```

How should I modify my calculation for seasonal/residual/trend to get something which I can add together?